# Javascript - DOM element regaining initial value after callback method exit

Tags: javascript, html, callback, socket.io

I have some callback methods for some socket.io events.
In one of the event, I change the body's `background-color` to red and in another event, I change it to yellow.

when I am debugging into the issue of why yellow is not being reflected, I see that during step by step debugging, the body's color is changing to yellow but as soon as the method gets finished it changes back to red.

Here are my two callback events.

```
function initScore(data) {

    $('body').css('background', 'red')  // <-- color changes and is saved

    $('.waiting-modal').hide()
    let j = JSON.parse(data);
    roundId = j.id;
    delete j.id
    players = j["players"];
    delete j["players"]
    $('#scores').html('')
    for (key in j) {
        console.log(j[key])
        $('#scores').append('<p><strong>' + j[key][0] + ': </strong>' + `${j[key][1].wins} / ${j[key][1].losses}` + '</p>')    
    }
}

function gameOver(data) {
    $('body').css('background', 'yellow')    // <-- changes to yellow but turns back red.
}
```

Here are my callback events

```
socket.on('init_scores', initScore)
socket.on('gameOver', gameOver);
```

This is a strange behavior I have never faced anytime.

Comment: did you try logging in each callback just before changing the background? 
Aren't you just receiving the init_score & gameOver one after the other ?

Comment: init_score is received first. after the round gets over gameOver is received